# Teamwork Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been working with RoR for a while but now I need to work with designers and other developers. Is there a tool like github or something like dropbox where you can share with your team the files but with a URL where you can check live any change. For example for my own I just run `Rails s` and I can see what happen on my localhost but for a designer it isn't that simple. And also we don't want everybody running his own rails project on his localhost.
So is there a tool or what do you do guys when you have to work with others collaborates?

Answer (score 0):

You consider to use a `staging environment`?

> A staging environment (stage) is a nearly exact replica of a production environment for software testing. Staging environments are made to test codes, builds, and updates to ensure quality under a production-like environment before application deployment. The staging environment requires a copy of the same configurations of hardware, servers, databases, and caches. Everything in a staging environment should be as close a copy to the production environment as possible to ensure the software works correctly.

See the [Font](https://searchsoftwarequality.techtarget.com/definition/staging-environment)

To use it, i recommend you a application like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), after configure, you can 'deploy' your app commiting in a branch (its not real time, but works for your case).

If you have a `VM`, i recommends you this tutorial: https://emaxime.com/2014/adding-a-staging-environment-to-rails.html

Comment: I actually use heroku for my projects, but for example if you are a web designer and you need to change something in the front-end they can edit it because the share files but they can't see it until somebody push the project to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Open questions like this are not really best placed on StackOverflow, which is geared more toward solving specific issues, with provided code examples and errors etc.

However, in answer to your question:

I see you mention Github in your question, but do you fully understand the underlying concept of [Git](https://git-scm.com/) Version Control, or is there a speficic reason as to why it doesn't meet your needs? As far as I believe, it's main purpose is to solve your exact scenario.

https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/